# Is it possible to use CSS defined colors directly on jsx tags?

Tags: reactjs

From CSS file:

```
:root {
    --color-accent: #E67E22;
}
```

Inside jsx file:

```
<h1> This is a word in <span style={{color:'#E67E22'}}> Orange </span></h1>
```

The result is the same, but I want to use my CSS --color-accent.

Comment: Doesn't `color: var(--color-accent)` work?

Comment: I was doing it without ' ' like in CSS and it would give me an error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the variable as a string:

```
<h1> This is a word in <span style={{ color:'var(--color-accent)' }}> Orange </span></h1>
```